# Sql Server agent can not start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2008-r2

I can not start Sql Server agent to create job. Can anyone help me? .
I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate , Sql server 2008 Rc2

See this images:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 10):

SQL Server Express Edition does not include SQL Agent functionality.

While the installer does register the service entry, the service will fail to start if you try. (I verified with one of my own instances -- the error message I got is exactly the same.)

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a comparison of features available in each edition of SQL Server 2008 R2.

If it's appropriate for what you need to accomplish, you can use the Windows Task Scheduler instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you upgraded your SQL Server instance from SQL Server Express, this link might explain and solve your problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955763

"The SQL Server Agent service does not start after you upgrade from SQL Server 2008 Express or from SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services to SQL Server 2008 Developer, to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise, or to SQL Server 2008 Standard"